# How to get wordpress to load a Jquery-ui libary

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to integrate a preexisting site into Wordpress. My site uses the jQuery-ui draggables and droppables. I'm having trouble getting Wordpress to load the jQuery-ui library. Right now I have it set up to use

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/JavaScript/JavaScript/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.js','',false);
```

But with this I get an error saying

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) \
```

I think I have a problem with how I am trying to link things in Wordpress because I am also getting errors on importing my images into the site.

Any help or ideas on what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the path `/JavaScript/JavaScript/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.js` exist in your theme's base directory? Have you followed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI is included in WP, so simply call:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );
```

complete list of included scripts [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).